# Qt 5.1.1: QWebView doesn't load local html file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've been struggling with an issue regarding loading a local html file. I'm going off the assumption that a QWebView is the correct way to be trying to display this file. My issue is that while I have the .html file visible when running in Debug, when I attempt to run in Release it is not visible. I am including the file in the appropriate directories, so that's no the issue. Are there any additional settings, libs, dlls that I could be missing? I've got the file specified to the QWebView in Qt Creator in the URL field of the QWebView. It is displayed like below:

```
file:///C:/devel/projects/myProject/myProject/Resources/page.htm
```

I've changed the file to a .html as well, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks,
-K

Edit: I've changed it temporarily to:

```
waiver_webView_2->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file:///C:/devel/projects/myProject/myProject/Resources/page.htm"));
```

Unfortunately this still does not work. I've verified and the file does actually exist there. When I provide that location to the URL via the Qt Creator it works on my developer machine in release but not on a machine I deploy to, DESPITE the folder structure being absolutely identical.

Comment: You write load. Try setUrl instead.

Comment: Use QUrl("file:///....") or QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/..."). fromLocalFile() builds the file:/// url from the path, so passing in `file:///` you end up with `file:file:///C:/...`

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Ahh, that makes sense. It ended up fixing it locally, but how would I format the URL path using a relative path? I'm trying to get this working on a separate machine that I deploy to. Currently trying but failing using: `waiver_webView_2->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("..\\Resources\\page.htm"));`

Answer (score 3):

The best I could find was getting the absolute path of the file first and then using that path with QUrl. There's a qt forum post on this topic which I'll put as a source bellow. It can be adapted to your code like so:

```
waiver_webView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("page.htm").absoluteFilePath()));
```

QFileInfo also needs to be included.

source https://forum.qt.io/topic/23653/qurl-fromlocalfile-and-relative-path/4